# SQL Insert Datype Number Insert Overflow Error

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, sql-insert

Please could any one help me on below error, with below insert statement?

**Line 1: Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.**

```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_test]([EMPLOYERCODE] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Tran_type] [char](3) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL
)



INSERT INTO Table_Test (EMPLOYERCODE
                                , SSN
                                    , Tran_type )
                            VALUES (91001
                                    , 799005001
                                    , 9 
                                    , CAST(18 As numeric(11, 2))
                                    , CAST(90 As numeric(11, 2))
                                    , CAST(11 As numeric(11, 2))
                                    , 4300485073
                                    , CAST('SST'  As char(3)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a thought, in your INSERT statement your 2 last castings:

```
CAST(90 As numeric(11, 2))
CAST(11 As numeric(11, 2))
```

seem not to be compatible with the CREATE TABLE statement:

```
[SSVAVGHRSWORKED] [numeric](3, 2) NULL,
[COMPLETENESS] [numeric](6, 2) NULL,
```

I would suggest you change either one.